# Error in R Tesseract

Tags: r, tesseract

I have the R Tesseract package working with the default eng.traineddata under OSX, but it simply won't find other languages.

```
trial <- ocr("test.png", engine = tesseract(language = "jpn", datapath="/Users/histmr/Library/R/3.3/library/tesseract/tessdata"))
```

Generates the error:

```
Failed loading language 'jpn'
Tesseract couldn't load any languages!
Error in tesseract_engine_internal(datapath, language) : 
Unable to find training data for: jpn
```

I've checked with

```
tesseract_info()
$datapath
[1] "/Users/histmr/Library/R/3.3/library/tesseract/tessdata/"

$available
[1] "eng" "jpn"

$version
[1] "3.05.00"
```

Sometimes I get references to a "TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable" but I don't know where that is. How can I get the correct directory path (I can see the file in the directory) or edit the "TESSDATA_PREFIX environment variable"?

The problem seems to occur with Japanese but NOT French

```
tesseract_download("fra")
french <- tesseract("fra")
```

Works fine! But

```
tesseract_download("jpn")    
japanese <- tesseract("jpn")
```

Generates an error

Comment: Have you found the solution? `chi_tra` and `chi_sim` had the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The error message `Error in tesseract_engine_internal(datapath, language)` said the language file, in your case `jpn.traineddata`, is not available in the `TESSDATA_PREFIX` which is the default path for storing all the trained language data. If you haven't set the path, you may open a terminal and type the command below.

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/Users/histmr/Library/R/3.3/library/tesseract/tessdata/
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Thanks! I've updated my query because I realized the problem is language specific

Comment: @MarkR So you have downloaded the correct `jpn` trained data to  'TESSDATA_PREFIX' path and it works?

Comment: No, strangely French works, but not Japanese. Although the training data is in the exact same directory

Comment: @MarkR can you share the image of  both languages?

Comment: What do you mean by image? Sorry, I don't quite follow

Comment: @MarkR I mean if you can edit your post to include sample French and Japanese.images to be used for OCR testing.

Comment: @MarkR saw the french_text. Have you managed to upload the Japanese text?

Comment: http://ocrapiservice.com/static/images/examples/french_text.png works great. With Japanese I get an error on engine creation, but here's a sample Japanese png: http://history.emory.edu/RAVINA/JF_text_mining/Japanese_sample.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144302/discussion-between-mark-r-and-thewaywewere).

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem is multiple installs of Tesseract (I used Homebrew and MacPorts) creating multiple TESSDATA folders. Strangely R was happier with a seemingly identical folder, but in a different place closer to root, ordinarily hidden under OSX. I got things working with

```
export TESSDATA_PREFIX=/opt/local/share
```

I hope this helps